# Get a difference file by specific patterns in two text files

Tags: regex, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have 2 text files and I need to export "changes" to a new file. That means that the second file's rows are compared to the first file's rows and if a row isn't found there, then it will append it to the new (third) file.

Contents of the first file are:

```
ABC 123 q1w2sd
DEF 321 sdajkn
GHI 123 jsdnaj
JKL 456 jsd223
```

The second file contains:

```
ABC 123 XXXXXX
JKL 456 jsd223
DEF XXX sdajkn
GHI 123 jsdnaj
```

Notice that lines which start with ABC and DEF have changed. JKL has just changed it's place.

The output file should contain:

ABC 123 XXXXXX
DEF XXX sdajkn

How to do this using 'awk' or 'sed'?

*Edit: Also new lines in the second file should be counted as changes..*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == FNR { f1[$0]; next } !($0 in f1)' file1 file2
```

With grep:
`grep -Fvxf file1 file2`

Comment: Doesn't this only compare the first column?

Comment: No, it compares the entire row.

Comment: @Dropout In `awk` `$0` is entire line. `$1` is first column, `$2` is second column and so on...

Comment: Wow this is really clear. Why would I check each column one by one when any changes in any rows export it to the third file. Great answer! :)

Comment: @JS웃 thanks, that was exactly the thing I didn't understand until now +1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 1st file is named: `fileA` and 2nd file is named: `fileB` you can use awk like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];b[$0];next} ($1 in a) && !($0 in b)' file{A,B}
```

OR simply:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];b[$0];next} ($1 in a) && !($0 in b)' file1 file2
```

Comment: are you storing each line's first column into "a" and "b"? I'm trying to understand that.. b[$0] means that the 0th(first) column is being stored to "b"? thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. Also the new lines, which were added to the second file should be counted as changes. Basically everything new or updated in comparison with the first file.

Comment: Yep, I figured it out probably.. I needed this: awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0];b[$1];c[$2];next} (($0 in a) && (!($1 in b) || !($2 in c))) || !($0 in a)' fileA fileB

Comment: Many thanks for your help, you made me go the right way. The answer was very close to that. +1

Comment: @Dropout: You're welcome. Sorry I was away from my computer and couldn't reply to your questions immediately. Great to see your problem got resolved.

Comment: Somehow I interpreted from `Notice that lines which start with ABC and DEF have changed` that you only want to print differences where 1st column is same in both file. Sorry bad interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed 's#\(.*\)#/\1/d#' file1|sed -f - file2
ABC 123 XXXXXX
DEF XXX sdajkn
```

This also treats "newlines" in `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `comm` to find lines in 2nd file that are not in 1st:

```
$ comm -13 <(sort first) <(sort second)
ABC 123 XXXXXX
DEF XXX sdajkn
```